# Prime numbers identifier with logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, primes, logistic-regression

is it possible to use logistic regression to identify prime numbers?
i´m trying to project a system with supervised logistic regression with a predefined database numbers and it´s classification (1 = Prime, 0 = Not Prime), using this data i want the computer to use this type of alghorythm to identify other numbers that aren´t classified on DB,
is it possible, or i´m trying to do something impossible?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that you can provide *features* that could serve for this discrimination?

Comment: i don´t undestand your question, but if you´re talking about the data, in my college, we have already made a database with this data, just for educational purpouse, and test codes, and now i will try to use this data to train some neural code to auto identify other numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the right network configuration and enough time, I don't know why it would be impossible.

It seems [others have had success with different models](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/could-a-neural-network-detect-primes) and you might get a better idea from them:

> Early success on prime number testing via artificial networks is presented in [A Compositional Neural-network Solution to Prime-number Testing, László Egri, Thomas R. Shultz, 2006](https://cloudfront.escholarship.org/dist/prd/content/qt5sg7n4ww/qt5sg7n4ww.pdf). The knowledge-based cascade-correlation (KBCC) network approach showed the most promise, although the practicality of this approach is eclipsed by other prime detection algorithms that usually begin by checking the least significant bit, immediately reducing the search by half, and then searching based other theorems and heuristics up to (‾‾√). However the work was continued with [Knowledge Based Learning with KBCC, Shultz et. al. 2006](http://www.psych.mcgill.ca/perpg/fac/shultz/personal/Recent_Publications_files/kbcc06.pdf).